# How can I get the RGB/Greyscale value fro a single pixel

Tags: processing, rgb, pixel, grayscale

I'm creating a code in Processing that applies a filter to a photo by going over each pixel, extracting the RGB/Grayscale value and modifying the RGB values. The program would take the grayscale value and run it through a few if/else statements to determine how much to modify the RGB values. So far I have this for the code but I'm stumped on how to extract the RGB/Gray values of a pixel

```processing
PImage method(PImage image) {
  
  loadPixels();
  image.filter(GRAY);
  
  for (int i = 0; i < image.width; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < image.height; j++) {

      //This part here is to store the RGB values
      float R;
      float G;
      float B;
      //Convert the RGB to Gray
      float coordCol = (0.2989*R) + (0.5870*G) + (0.1140*B);
      
      if (coordCol < 60) {
        
        float rDark = R * 0.9;
        float gDark = G * 0.9;
        float bDark = B * 0.9;
      
      } else if(60 <= coordCol && coordCol <= 190) {
        
        float bTintBro = B * 0.7;
        
      } else { 
          float bTintYel = B * 0.9;
        
      }

    }
      
  }
  
  return image;  // change this to return a new PImage object
  
}
```

I've tried many methods, get(), pixel[], filter(GRAY), etc but so far I still can't get the RGB values for a pixel

Comment: Why not? What seems to be the problem? Both `get` and `pixel` do exactly that, so what exactly did you try and how did it not work?

Answer (score 3):

It's a question many will ask themselves because processing encodes it's colors in a non-intuitive manner. But you're in luck, because they totally know about it being that way! The helpful folks that coded Processing made a couple methods that will get you exactly what you want. [Here's the documentation for the one to get the R value](https://processing.org/reference/red_.html), you should be able to track the others from there.

Also, here's a short proof of concept demonstrating how to get the ARGB values from your sketch:

```
int rr, gg, bb, aa;
PImage bg;

void setup() {
  size(600, 400);

  // now setting up random colors for a test background
  bg = createImage(width, height, RGB);
  bg.loadPixels();
  for (int i=0; i<width*height; i++) {
    bg.pixels[i] = color(random(200), random(200), random(200), random(200));
  }
  updatePixels();
}

void draw() {
  background(bg);

  // giving visual feedback
  fill(255);
  textSize(15);
  text("R: " + rr, 10, 20);
  text("G: " + gg, 10, 40);
  text("B: " + bb, 10, 60);
  text("A: " + aa, 10, 80);
}

// THIS IS WHERE THE INFO YOU WANT IS
void mouseClicked() {
  loadPixels();
  int index = mouseX*mouseY;
  rr = (int)red(pixels[index]);
  gg = (int)green(pixels[index]);
  bb = (int)blue(pixels[index]);
  aa = (int)alpha(pixels[index]);
}
```

I hope it helps. Have fun!

Comment: Useful - thank you!  Can you clarify the syntax you are using for the rr etc assigments, with the round brackets in front of the expression.  Haven't run into it in the Processing documentation. Looks like casting?  (Also looks like one of those things from Java you are supposed to automagically know....)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply: yes, it's casting, more precisely it's "explicit typecasting", which is native in java. It's when the programmer forces the compiler to typecast in a specific way. Here I make sure that whatever I store in the 'rr' variable, which has memory set up to receive an integer, will by casted as an integer, whatever it was before. I'm doing it here because the methods I'm using are returning floats instead of integers. I use this a lot when ninja coding too, to be honest.